# placement of "different colors"

Tags: phrase-choice

(1) Jack likes to wear **different colors of** gloves.

(2) Jack likes to wear gloves **in different colors**.

(3) Jack likes to wear gloves **of different colors**.

I am not sure which sentence(s) make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible meanings here. One is that Jack likes blue on Monday, red on Tuesday, green on Wednesday etc. The third sentence admirably and idiomatically expresses that.

Another possibility is that he like to wear one colour on the left another on the right. The second sentence COULD BE suggesting that, but without clarity. If that were the case there are better ways of explaining it. I would simply say that "Jack likes to wear odd and non-matching gloves."

The first sentence is clunky - and not really idiomatic.